# How to make quotas for snap work?

Tags: snap

I’m confused on snap set-quota, respectively how to make it work. I followed [the quote-groups documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/quota-groups) and it all works, quota groups are there and I can assign snaps.

However, the quota gropus seems to have no impact. When I set an intentionally low quota like

`sudo snap set-quota lowmemory --memory=64MB` or `sudo snap set-quota one-cpu --cpu=1x5%`

and assign them to e.g. the Firefox snap e.g. `sudo snap set-quota one-cpu firefox` it seems to have no impact. `snap quota one-cpu` shows that everything is assigned, but the Firefox still is able to use more CPU and memory than it should be allowed to do.

Do I miss something or are any additional steps necessary?

I use Ubuntu 22.04 with Kernel 6.2 and currently snapd 2.60.4